# Android: creating email with relative content

Tags: android, html, email

I'm trying to create email with tables, divs and other components. When I'm using **Html.fromHtml(body)** it doesn't convert tags to proper structure. Divs with *float:left;* are not in the same line, table dissapear.

**How Can I create a relative content?** Is it possible?

Comment: "I'm trying to create email with tables, divs and other components" -- if you are intending to send this via `ACTION_SEND`, the email client most likely will lose lots of that formatting. `Html.fromHtml()` does not support arbitrary HTML. In particular, it does not support tables, and it only supports `<div>` in certain scenarios. Also, it does not support most CSS.

Comment: @CommonsWare so how can I resolve this problem? there is no way to find a solution?

Comment: How are you planning on sending this email?

Comment: @CommonsWare Create intent with **ACTION_SEND**, add **EXTRA_TEXT** with prepared HTML and open an e-mail client.

Answer (score 0):

There are many different email client apps for Android.

None have to support HTML **at all**.

Most that support rich formatting use the subset of capabilities offered by `EditText`. That does not include "tables, divs and other components". Attempts to provide those sorts of things, or CSS, or JavaScript, or whatever, will be stripped out via `Html.fromHtml()`.

Some email clients may use a `WebView` with a rich editor. It is possible that this editor will handle "tables, divs and other components". But, many rich editors on the Web do not, or at least do not support arbitrary starting HTML.

Your choices are:

1. Use HTML that is likely to degrade gracefully, given the wide range of HTML support in email clients, or
2. Do not use `ACTION_SEND` to send the email (e.g., upload the message to your Web server, which sends the email)